# access count variable defined in setinterval javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a count variable inside setInterval function i want to access this count variable outside.Please suggest.My code snippet is given below.

```js
 (function(){
    var count=0;
    setInterval(function(){ 
      count=count+1;
      //able to access count.
      console.log(count);
    }, 1000)
     //I am not able to access count here.
    console.log(count);
 })()
```

Comment: can not reproduce (no error occur), [mcve] please

Comment: Why can't you access it? It's printing `0`, that's the value of the variable before the internval function runs. The variable doesn't get updated until 1 second after that code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outside `console.log(count)` is running before the interval has had a chance to update the variable.

If you run it later, it will access the updated variable. For instance, you can access it in an event handler, and it will show the new value.

```js
(function() {
  var count = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    count = count + 1;
    //able to access count.
    console.log(count);
  }, 1000)

  document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerText = count;
  });
})()
```

```html
<button id="b">Show counter</button>
<br> Counter value: <span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot immediately access the count since the set interval method has to be called.

If you access it immediately as shown in the code, you will end up with the initial value that was called before the set interval method.

You can console your value after a time and see that the count is updated.
Javascript is asynchronous.

Comment: but i need updated count value is there any way to do the same.

Comment: You have defined the count value yourself that it will be updated everytime after 1 second. So, you will have to wait for 1 second atleast before retrieving the new value of count.

Comment: Can i assign count variable to other global variable and I can get updated value from new variable.